# Last sent e-mail from Mail.app with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

Is there any way to get the last sent e-mail from Mail? 
It can only access the top level sent mailbox.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set mabo to the sent mailbox
    set selected to messages of mabo
    return properties of item 1 of selected
end tell
```

The reason I need this is that I want to get information about the e-mail that is beeing written. My thought was to get the frontmost window.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set the win to windows
    set theMessage to item 1 of win
    get name of theMessage
end tell
```

It is working for the name but I do not get the sender or receipient. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, you just have to loop through each account, and each time, compare the date of the email with previous email date from other account.
here is the script : (I also add a test in case the sent box of one account is empty !)

```
tell application "Mail"
set LastDate to date "samedi 1 janvier 2000 00:00:00"
set {myLastMail, myAccount, myDate} to {"", "", LastDate}
repeat with CAccount in every account
    if (count of every message in mailbox "Sent Messages" of CAccount) > 0 then
        set X to first message of mailbox "Sent Messages" of CAccount
        set MDate to date sent of X
        if MDate > LastDate then
            set LastDate to MDate
            set {myLastMail, myAccount, myDate} to {X, CAccount, LastDate}
        end if
    end if
end repeat
-- the last email from all your accounts is the variables  Mylastemail, in account MyAccount and at the date MyDate
end tell
```

Comment: this is actually what i was looking for. But it still does not work. `set LastDate to date "samedi 1 janvier 2000 00:00:00"`was not working so i exchangen it with `set LastDate to (current date) - (24 * 60 * 60)` but it crashes with the message `„mailbox \"Sent Messages\" of item 4 of every account“ cannot be read`.

Comment: sorry for the date, when you type "01/01/2000", ScriptEditor convert it to string format date and my system in French (= Janvier) while your system only understand english (January). solved.

Comment: the error you get is probably because you do not have sent mailbox at all for your account 4. there are 2 ways to solve this : 1) create the sent mailbox for your account 4, by just sending an email to you ! 2) add an "if" test to check if Caccount has or not a sent mailbox

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the messages in the sent mailbox are unsorted in the AppleScript array.

You can use this code, but it could take a while depending on the number of messages in the mailbox (ca. 30 sec for 1000 messages).

```
tell application "Mail"
    set sentMessages to messages of sent mailbox
    set lastestMessage to item 1 of sentMessages
    set latestDate to date received of lastestMessage

    repeat with aMessage in sentMessages
        if date received of contents of aMessage comes after latestDate then
            copy contents of aMessage to lastestMessage
            set latestDate to date received of lastestMessage
        end if
    end repeat
    tell lastestMessage
        set theSender to sender
        set theRecipient to 1st recipient
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: but this will only us the sent mailbox '(sent mailbox (mailbox, r/o) : The top level Sent mailbox)' if i send something from another mail account that is not top level it wont get it.

Comment: Actually if you've assigned the sent mailbox of your account to the standard sent mailbox ( via the `use this mailbox for ...' menu item ) the messages will appear in the top sent mailbox.

Comment: but i have 4 mail. icannot change it before i send the e-mail. is there no way to check this with applescript?

Comment: to check what? Of course you can refer to specific mailboxes with `mailbox "Sent Messages" of account "MyAccount"` instead of `sent mailbox.` Messages just created but not sent yet are in mailbox `outgoing messages` but are not editable with AppleScript

Comment: Right after the email was sent i would like to save the id of the last sent mail no matter what account i use.  But it seems i can only access the top level account.

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow uses to work for me in all my Mail versions up to 4.6 (Snow Leopard). To be tested on later versions. Strangely, "last message" gives the oldest message in the mailbox and the "first message" gives the last message sent or received ! if you have many accounts, just loop on accounts names :

```
tell application "Mail"
-- to get the last message sent
set X to first message of mailbox "Sent Messages" of account "your_account_name"
-- to get the oldest message received in receiving box
set X to last message of mailbox "INBOX" of account "your_account_name"
open X --if want to see it
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. But looping over the account would not tell me which one was the last sent email, but only tell me the last sent ones of each mailbox.

Comment: As mentioned, il you loop through each account, and each time, keep the first email whose date is later than previous, you get it !